# How can resources be cleaned-up when using Suspense?

Tags: reactjs, react-suspense

React async code is usually written along these lines (when clean-up is desired):

```
useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const signal = controller.signal;
  const promise = getResource(id, { signal })

  // set data when complete
  promise.then(data => setData(data));

  // Cancel operation if need to clean-up
  return () => controller.abort();
}, [getResource, id])
```

How can something similar be achieved with Suspense?

Do I need to write a pure clean-up effect for my clean-up needs, separate from suspense?

This applies not just to aborted requests, but also disconnecting from socket connections, leaving channels, etc.

Comment: What are you doing to trigger suspense? Are you manually throwing a promise (if so, please show that code), or are you using some library which internally throws a promise (if so, what library)? Also, you talk about using a socket; typically those will feed multiple values over time, not just one value, so they're not typically a good match for promises. Are you wanting suspense to finish after the first value is emitted, at which point the socket gets torn down?